# Where to perform validation related to length, format for mobile app: on server side or app side?

Tags: javascript, android, validation, mobile, client-server

We are developing Android mobile app that will have about 8-10 screens with about 10 fields on each screen. On each screen we need to "submit" data to server. Where we should perform validation related to length, format- on server side or app side? If we do it on app side, we have a limitation to do it using JavaScript. We want views in consideration to performance impact and ease of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should validate both on the client side and server side.

**Client side:**
Validating on the client side makes you application snappier because you'll not have to wait for the response from the server before showing any information about incorrect format, length or required fields to the user. It also enables you to handle validation in real time which will result in a much UX. I don't understand why you would do it with javascript of you are writing an Android application. [This](http://blog.zasadnyy.org.ua/2013/08/android-form-validation-right-way.html) article has some information about it.

**Server side:**
This is where you guard against incorrect data. The checks on the server side will almost never be needed because they've already been made by the client. The checks are simply there to prevent anyone from circumventing the client side checks and passing bogus data.

If you only want to or can implement one of these it should be the server side checking.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity of UI logic is common problem. But it is obvious that you should organize your code in the way when you can add any checks. To debug application (running on phone) you can try to use Android 4.4 and [remote debugging of WebView](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).

Also I guess you should perform validation on server side. Logic must accept or reject data incoming to chain of processing. Also it can be possible that somebody will call your logic, not only your own app.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to perform a double validation, both on client and server side.

Assuming that data validation is a simple CPU bound operation, and can be quickly done by any mobile device in a reasonable time (i.e. not impact on performances), a first client-side validation prevent your app to perform potentially useless network requests, which means  network useless traffic generation and depending of the user's contract with his Telco operator may imply a cost. Plus, this is an extra effort for your backend system to process invalid data, and even if one single validation is a simple operation, since you may (hopefully) have many application instances installed  on several devices this effort will be multiplied and  cause a big load for the server.

Nonetheless you can't avoid a final server side validation, cause we live in the real world and not in an ideal one, and any client side operation can't ever be considered safe at all!

The technology you are using (javascript in your case) does not affect or influence the above considerations! All technologies provide sufficient ready-to-use validation and debugging tools!